# Connecting I/O peripherals to general purpose (evaluation kit) MCU

Tags: microcontroller, connector, soldering, io, peripheral

I'm new to electronics and am interested in playing around with an evaluation kit [like this one](https://www.microchip.com/DevelopmentTools/ProductDetails/PartNO/ATSAMR21-XPRO#additional-summary).

It *looks* like those pins sticking out of it are GPIO pins, but I can't find a picture that zooms in close enough on it to see what each pin is labeled as.

My question: if those pins sticking out of the MCU *are* in fact GPIO pins, how does one typically connect IO peripherals (camera, motor, LED, etc.) to it? Solder? Are there special "port"-type connectors that you solder the IO leads to and then snap on to the pins? What are my options here for connecting peripherals?

Comment: Stack exchange sites are reserved for *specific* questions.  For a general introduction to a topic and the variety of choices, you'll need to use traditional reference materials instead.  Likely at the beginning you'll find it easiest to use combinations of MCU + peripheral + software which someone else has already demonstrated compatible as your starting point.  So perhaps start your searching based on the types of goals you'd like to achieve, and see what people have been using to implement similar projects.

Comment: Sure, thanks @ChrisStratton (+1) -- specifically, what are my options for connecting an LED to the GPIO pins on this specific MCU (if they are in fact GPIO pins?!)?

Comment: On Amazon, search for "arduino wires". Female to female wires are often used to connect to peripheral devices. Female to male wires are often used to connect to a wireless breadboard. Separate the wires as necessary (they pull apart easily).

Comment: Thanks @Mattman944 (+1) so it sounds like: **(a)** a female-to-female connector would be usable here, and would allow me to reuse the board across various hobby applications. **(b)** there's nothing stopping me from soldering the peripherals onto the pins, although that makes it much more permanent. Is that a fair summary? Also, I guess **(c)** the GPIO pins on that MCU, can you tell if they are a particular "type" or format? When I search Amazon for female-to-female connectors, I get a million different results for all different types of connectors... thanks again!

Comment: Given the questions you are asking you probably don't want to start with that MCU board, but rather one which has more community/hobbyist support resources around it.

Comment: Thanks again @ChrisStratton (and +1 again), I **totally** understand and appreciate that you don't know the answer to the question here, I'm just hoping someone here has an understanding of how to figure out what "type" of GPIO pins are on this MCU, so I can figure out what my connection options are.

Comment: The *various* types of GPIO pins on the SAMR21 chip and the which are brought out where on a particular board are amply documented the respective manufacturer reference materials.  It's because reading and interpreting those is perhaps not a beginner task, and because you're written nothing which would hint this board has any unique suitability as a choice for you, that you should probably pick something with more support aimed at beginner/hobby users, rather than just what practicing engineers considering this vs. other choices would need to inform our decisions.

Comment: There is something called "datasheet", "schematic", "user-guide" etc they give with every evaluation board.

Comment: These are "Berg" headers  0.64mm square pins spaced 2.54mm apart. but nobody calls them "Berg" any more. The cables are called "Dupont" cables for no apparent reason.

Comment: _"I'm new to electronics and am interested in playing around with an evaluation kit like this one."_ - what do you mean by '**like** this one', is it that one or not? If not, which one is it?

Comment: you plug ribbon cables into those connectors

Comment: Yeah but Bruce Abbott, think about it, if I crimp those Berg headers into the base without any solder, which GPIO pin will it be wired to without knowing the type? Also much thanks Lundin who knew and was able to articulate the answer here! Thanks so much to all!

Comment: Note that individual wires (described in my comment) are good for "playing around". Lundin's answer is good for a finished project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the documentation that comes with the board rather than looking at the picture.

The connectors in this case are standard double row socket strips, pitch 0.1''/2.54mm. Easiest way to connect to these for hobbyist is to buy a "2.54mm crimping tool kit", of which there are plenty on the market & can be bought on Amazon etc ([example](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Preciva-Crimping-Connectors-0-1-1-0mm%C2%B2-Connector/dp/B07QNPZDTW/ref=sr_1_3?crid=21N4EGK06N1WJ&dchild=1&keywords=dupont+crimping+tool&qid=1606294771&s=diy&sprefix=dupont+c%2Cdiy%2C179&sr=1-3)). It comes with a bunch of connectors, crimps and wires (should be AWG22 to AWG26) - make sure that it also includes the actual tool. Popular brands are JST and TE/AMP.

The advantage of crimp style connectors for these purposes is that you can usually "undo" individual wires and remove them from the connector. The other side of it can be soldered or attached to whatever specific connector is needed for the application.

You can of course just remove the connectors and solder straight onto the board too, but that's inconvenient if you want to re-use the board for more than one project.